# visibility hidden in li

Tags: css, html-lists, visibility

I have this piece of html code :

```
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tab"> <a href="#" @click="show('infos')"> Infos </a> </li>
  <li class="tab"> <a href="#" @click="show('modules')"> Modules </a>
</li>
```

```
<ul class="content-tabs">
  <li class="tab infos">
    @include('layouts.forms.trainingsForm')
  </li>
  <li class="tab modules">
    modules
  </li>
</ul>
```

when I click on one of the links it should display the content of

in the last  by assigning the class "active" to the appropriate

. Here is the css part for the li :

```
ul.content-tabs {
 border: solid 1px #ececec;
 margin: 7px 0px; 
}

ul.content-tabs li.tab {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

ul.content-tabs li.active {
  visibility: visibile !important;
}
```

the problem now is that even if the li has the class "active" it won't show up because the "visibility: hidden;" applied to ul.content-tabs li.tab ( after some debugging in the developer tool) .

Comment: You have a typo: `visibile` must be `visible`. I'm 100% certain the developer tools show you that error.

Comment: This question should be closed.

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It seems that `ul.content-tabs li.tab` is more detailed than `ul.content-tabs li` so try setting:

```
ul.content-tabs li.tab.active {
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: You fail to see the real source of the problem and even copied it to your answer. Also you probably mean "specific" rather than "detailed". And no, it's not *more specific*. A *really* bad answer.

Comment: I see, you're absolutely correct, sorry :)

Comment: This answer should be deleted by its author.